# How do I calculate the probability of a normally distributed event that has mutual exclusion?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If you are familiar with `Iron Condors` as they relate to options trading, you'll know that if you're selling an iron condor, then you are safe as long as a stock trades within a range.

However, if it goes to the upper end of the range, then the lower end has no chance of being hit. And vice versa.

So is the probability of the whole event simply the smaller of the 2 probabilities?

If this question is unclear, please ask for clarification and I'm happy to adjust this post.

Comment: I think you'll get a better response if you define your terms (the concept you are asking about is very easy to describe).  That said, I do know what an Iron Condor is and I have no idea what you are asking.  Probability of what?  What underlying process do you wish to assume?

Comment: Just to clarify (possibly):  imagine a model in which the underlying can only move to one of three states at expiry.  Let $P_0$ denote the probability that it ends in the state between the option spreads, $P_+$ the probability that it ends above the higher call, and $P_-$ the probability that it ends below the lowest put.  Then your probability of loss is $P_++P_-$.

Comment: @lulu - how can that be? If it goes below the lowest put, then doesn't `P+` equal 0?

Comment: After the event has happened there is no probability left, there is just the value whatever it is.  Before the event we have some distribution and we have to add up all the bad cases to determine the loss probability.

Comment: Say you are throwing a fair die and you win if you throw a $3,4$ but lose otherwise.  Then the bad cases are $1,2,5,6$ and the probability of a loss is $\frac 46$.  Saying "but if it comes up $6$ then it can't have come up $1$"  doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: @lulu can you write this as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: Just wrote something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the expiry of the options, all we have is a list of possible outcomes and their probabilities.  You have to add up (or integrate over) the loss cases to get the loss probability.  Knowing that the occurrence of one bad event precludes the occurrence of another has nothing to do with it.

An example:  Suppose you are making a bet on a fair die and you win if it comes up $3,4$ but lose otherwise.  (Note: this is what the Iron Condor payout looks like). Then your loss probability is $\frac 46$ as there are four bad cases out of the possible six and all are equally likely.  It is of course true that, if the die comes up $5$ then it can't have come up $1$ but this does not help you.  In the discrete case, the probability that one of a list of mutually exclusive events will occur is the sum of the probabilities (this is one of the core axioms of probability).